# JPA rest stops working when trying to upload blob

Tags: java, jpa

My whole rest service stops working when I'm adding this code:

```
@PUT
@Path("upload/{id}")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public void addBlob(@PathParam("id") Integer id, @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream) throws IOException {
    TheTempClient entityToMerge = find(id);
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int read = 0;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
        while ((read = uploadedInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            out.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }
        entityToMerge.setTestBlob(out.toByteArray());
        super.edit(entityToMerge);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

It doesn't really say why either, all I'm getting is:

```
Severe:   WebModule[/MavenProjectTest]StandardWrapper.Throwable
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ModelValidationException: Validation of the application resource model has failed during application initialization.
```

And a bunch of errors saying " *caused by previous errors* "

I must have done something really wrong here, are there any proffessional JPA enthusiasts that can help me out a little bit here?

Edit: I'm using annotations instead of web.xml, is it possible to do this without a web.xml?

Comment: This is a misconfiguration in your Jersey service. And the bunch of error log after that is really important to find the root cause out.

Comment: Is `InputStream` allowed as `FormDataParam`? I thought you need some MultiPart-Library for that...

Comment: @slartidan I'm honestly not completely sure, I'm new to this, but I followed this guide: http://www.javatpoint.com/jax-rs-file-upload-example

Comment: Did you add `org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature` to init param in your `web.xml`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to add `register(MultiPartFeature.class);`

in the `ApplicationConfig.java` class, like this:

```
@javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath("api")
public class ApplicationConfig extends ResourceConfig {

public ApplicationConfig() {
    packages("com.test.thepackage.service");
    register(MultiPartFeature.class);
}
```

}

Now it works like a charm, without a web.xml file.